# Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault in UBUNTU 18.04 LTS Server?

Tags: python, php, python-2.7, ubuntu-18.04, advantage-database-server

I am getting this error while I test my program/server/database using a php file inserting data in every 1 second. Here are code and errors

PHP

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
include("class.php");
// new class for xmlhttp connection
?>
<html><h1>Load Balancing</h1>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function(){
d=new Date();
d1 = (d.getMonth()+1)+"/"+d.getDate()+"/"+d.getFullYear()+" "+d.getHours()+":"+d.getMinutes()+":"+d.getSeconds()+":"+d.getMilliseconds();
$.ajax({ url:'./generator.php', cache : false, success: function(data){
    $('#resultarea1').val(data.foo);
    $('#resultarea2').val(d1);
    $('#submit').click();
}, dataType: "json"});
}, 1000);
</script>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<table border="0">
  <tr><td>Random ID: </td><td><input type="text" id="resultarea1" name="randid"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Random TS:</td><td> <input type="text" id="resultarea2" name="rantsp" ></td><tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</html>
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  // collect value of input field
  $useid = $_REQUEST['randid'];
  $usejdate = $_REQUEST['rantsp'];
  if (empty($useid)) {
      echo "ID is empty";
  } else {
$call = new XMLHttpRequest;
$call->open("POST","127.0.0.1:5000/api/insertLB");
$call->setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
$call->setRequestHeader("X-Api-Key-Auth","asoidewfoef");
// sending the request
$call->send('{"payload" : { "useid": '.$useid.',  "usejdate": "'.$usejdate.'"}}');
  }
}

?>
```

Python file

```
import faulthandler; faulthandler.enable()
import adsdb
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import json
import time 
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
from json import dumps

app = Flask(__name__)

#error handling
@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(e):
    return render_template("404.html") #this file comes in template folder of the app

#restful_api assign
api = Api(app)

#connection to adsdb 
conn = adsdb.connect(DataSource='/data/company/general/general.add', ServerType='3', UserId='adssys', Password='')
#define a cursor to connection
curs = conn.cursor()

#trying a datetime function to convert adsdb date - not completed

def date_time(x):
    x1 = datetime.combine(x, datetime.min.time())
    date_time_str = x1
    #print type(date_time_str) #datetime.datetime
    #date_time_obj = date_time_str.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    date_time_obj = date_time_str.strftime('%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S:%f')
    return date_time_obj


class dbInsertLB(Resource):
    def post(self):
        if not request.is_json:
           # exit(400)  # or any custom BadRequest message
           return ({"message" : "Invalid Content Type"})
        else:
            headers = request.headers
            auth = headers.get("X-Api-Key-Auth")
            if auth == 'asoidewfoef':
                json_object = json.dumps(request.data)
                if  json.loads(json_object): 
                    json_object = json.dumps(request.data)
                    if json.loads(json_object): 
                       item_dict = json.loads(request.data) 
                       # here is assiging to vars                
                       useid = str(item_dict['payload']['useid'])
                       usejdate = item_dict['payload']['usejdate']
                       curs.execute("insert into checkload (randid, rantsp) values ('" + str(useid) +"', '"+ str(usejdate) +"')")
                       conn.commit()
                    return ({"message" : "Invalid Josn"})
            else: return ({"message" : "Invalid Api Key or no api key found in headers"})            

#defining route url path for the specific defined in each classes

api.add_resource(dbInsertLB, '/api/insertLB') #route7


#define app host port debug options for api server here 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Error In Details

```
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Thread 0x00007fb9fed7a700:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adsdb.py", line 523 in new_statement
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adsdb.py", line 570 in executemany
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adsdb.py", line 600 in execute
  File "/r_data/data_entry/myapp6.py", line 55 in post
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 595 in dispatch_request
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 89 in view
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 480 in wrapper
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936 in dispatch_request
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950 in full_dispatch_request
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447 in wsgi_app
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464 in __call__
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/debug/__init__.py", line 304 in debug_application
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 314 in execute
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 323 in run_wsgi
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 379 in handle_one_request
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 340 in handle
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 345 in handle
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 655 in __init__
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334 in finish_request
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 599 in process_request_thread
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801 in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 774 in __bootstrap

Current thread 0x00007fb9fe539700:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adsdb.py", line 584 in executemany
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adsdb.py", line 600 in execute
  File "/r_data/data_entry/myapp6.py", line 55 in post
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 595 in dispatch_request
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 89 in view
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 480 in wrapper
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936 in dispatch_request
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950 in full_dispatch_request
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447 in wsgi_app
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464 in __call__
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/debug/__init__.py", line 304 in debug_application
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 314 in execute
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 323 in run_wsgi
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 379 in handle_one_request
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 340 in handle
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 345 in handle
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 655 in __init__
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334 in finish_request
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 599 in process_request_thread
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801 in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 774 in __bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fb9ff5bb700:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 150 in _eintr_retry
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 231 in serve_forever
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 777 in serve_forever
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1009 in inner
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801 in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 774 in __bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fba03cd0740:
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 214 in run
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 337 in run_with_reloader
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1050 in run_simple
  File "/home/adssys/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 990 in run
  File "/r_data/data_entry/myapp6.py", line 68 in <module>
```

What I did is from a browser chrome with multiple tabs approximately 20 tabs each tab with url pointing to this php page. after inserting nearly 1000 rows or just for a couple of minutes the program will crash giving me this error. If I reduce the tab and put this url from two more other systems It will run for approx 20 minutes and the program crash. Please let me know if there a way to solve this issue.

My Version are
PHP 7.*
Python 2.7
Advantage Database Server 12
Ubuntu 18.*

Thanks in advantance

Comment: This is a bug in the Python implementation, not something you can fix. Python 2.7 is EOL, you should convert to Python 3.x

Comment: since adsdb (database connector) support is limitted to python 2.7 we are using this version. @Barmar

Comment: I tried to run the code in python3 availabe in ubuntu and the error received from database driver adsdb is "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'" Is there any way to by pass this ?

Comment: Looks like Advantage hasn't been updated in over 4 years. It doesn't sound like a current product.

Comment: I don't know whether it relates to your error, but I would consider implementing/using some kind of connection pooling solution rather than relying on a single connection and cursor, which is what the code in the example is doing.

Comment: can you recommend any example ? @snakecharmerb

Comment: To check whether the single db connection is the cause the segfault you could try: (1) create a new db connection and cursor for each request and close them once the request completes - this will likely be slow (2) Try creating a bunch of connections in a `collections.deque` when the module is initialised.  in the route function, pop a connection and use it for that request, put it back at the beginning of the deque when you've finished with it.  If the deque is empty a request either waits (`time.sleep`) or returns  500; this is a primitive connection pool for testing, not good for production